# If $A$ and $B$ are two sets containing 3 and 6 elements respectively

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given, $n(A)=3$, $n(B)=6$. Find the maximum and minimum value of $n(A\cup B)$.

My attempt
$n(A\cup B)$ will be maximum if $n(A\cap B)$ is minimum (i.e $n(A\cap B)=0$)

So, $n(A\cup B)= 3+6=9$.

Am i right? Please help further

Comment: Let $A\subset B$ so $A\cap B=A$.

Comment: @MyGlasses, for what purpose $A\subset B$?

Comment: Perhaps $n(A)=3<6=n(B)$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right.
$$
n(A \cup B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A \cap B)
$$
Since $n(A)$ and $n(B)$ are fixed, $n(A \cup B)$ is maximum when $n(A \cap B)$ is minimum.
$n(A \cap B)$ is always positive and is equal to zero when $A$ et $B$ are disjoints.

Comment: What's different between **maximal** and **maximum** ?

Comment: [Mh](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38260/maximum-vs-maximal), alright I should use _maximum_ instead of _maximal_, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have $n(A \cup B)=n(A)+n(B)-n(A \cap B)=9-n(A \cap B)$.

Furthermore, since $A \cap B \subseteq A$, the follwing values for $n(A \cap B)$ are possible:

$0,1,2$ and $3$.